# Error Resolving Dependencies from Maven Repository

Tags: maven, artifactory, jfrog-cli, maven-central, jfrog-xray

I have created a Maven Repository over Jfrog Artifactory using https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Maven+Repository. I have created Maven Repo in all as a REMOTE Repo with the url being pointed to "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/". I have received the settings.xml file as well from artifactory which I have configured in my project. 
Whilst using the settings.xml file and trying to resolve the dependency of a sample project, I get the following error:

> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
>   **Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.**

I can confirm that the credentials are correct yet the issue persists. Can someone please help me out??

Comment: Please show the `settings.xml` file entries cause obviously the credentials are not correct or not configured at the right place.

Comment: Looks at the Artifactory access and request logs can also help with debugging the issue - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Logging

Comment: Hi All, I resolved the issue myself. I had to make changes to the getCurrentUser as well as the password section of it. Now I am able to resolve the dependencies using my local Jfrog Artifactory.

Comment: @genius_monkey - You might want to consider deleting this question since it's unlikely to provide anything useful to anybody else.